# Why am I forced to reference types in unused constructors?

Tags: c#, class-constructors

Let's say that I have a class (`ClassA`) containing one method which calls the constructor of another class, like this:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public void CallClassBConstructor()
    {
        using(ClassB myB = new ClassB()) {...}
    }
}
```

The class `ClassB` looks like this:

```
public class ClassB : IDisposable
{
    public ClassB(){}
    public ClassB(string myString){}
    public ClassB(ClassC myC){}
    public void Dispose() {...}
}
```

...and `ClassC` is even more simple:

```
public class ClassC{}
```

If I put these classes in their own assembly and compile the whole solution I don't get any errors. But if I replace the using statement with this:

```
using(ClassB myB = new ClassB("mystring")){...}
```

I get a compile error asking me to add a reference to `[mynamespace].ClassC` in `ClassA`. Since I'm not calling `ClassB(ClassC myC)` at all this makes no sense to me - why do I have to include the types of other constructors regardless of whether I use them or not? What if `ClassC` was included in a licensed or hard-to-aquire assembly? Is this an example of bad design that developers should avoid or am I missing something here?

Comment: This can not compile in the first place, ClassB does not implement IDisposable. Then it can not be used in a using clause.

Comment: This is not C/C++ where invalid unused code will silently be ignored if the sections are gc'd by the linker.

Comment: I edited the code so that it should compile now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has to do with method overload resolution when calling the `ClassB` constructor.

When you call the constructor with no parameters, there is no contention. There is only one candidate, so it is chosen. It is not necessary for `ClassA` to reference `ClassC` in this case.

However, when you call the constructor with one parameter, then at the outset both of the single-parameter constructors are candidates. In order to resolve this call, the compiler needs to know about `ClassC`. For all you know, `ClassC` could contain an implicit conversion operator, for example.

(Of course we know that in this particular example such an implicit conversion operator wouldn’t fire anyway because there is a perfect match that takes a string — but the method overload resolution rules are defined this way to make them very well-defined and predictable. Imagine it were designed in such a way that adding a reference could cause your code to suddenly call a different constructor overload.)

Comment: Thanks Timwi, I think all the answers made it pretty clear to me :-)

Comment: How come a missing `using` statement is not enough for the compiler to know which overload to use? I'm confused that simply adding the reference makes the compiler happy.

Comment: @Stijn: You probably mean the [`using` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx), *not* the [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). But even so, neither the question nor my answer have anything to do with `using` statements *or* `using` directives. They are about [references to other assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). The `using` declaration does not add such a reference.

Comment: Indeed I meant the `using` directive. I do believe OP and me had the same problem though. I had to add a reference to an assembly for a constructor overload that I'm not using. And now I was wondering why it doesn't know that I don't want to use that specific overload, when the required `using` to gain access to the class used in the overload is missing. Perhaps I should open a new question?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the constructor overloads, the compiler needs to know the types involved. I.e. it needs to know `ClassC` in order to pick the right constructor overload for `ClassB`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Brian - it concurred nicely with the other answers

Answer (score 1):

It is because `ClassC`, which you have placed in a separate assembly, is part of the public interface of `ClassB` since it is a parameter of one of the constructors. You must reference the containing assembly of this type otherwise the compiler has no idea how to resolve the type information. In this specific case the compiler must resolve all parameter types from all constructor overloads so that it can choose the right one, but this is not a member overloading issue per se. This happens anytime the compiler must resolve type information. It can happen on return types as well.

Comment: Why the downvote? Even before my edit this answer was not wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new on stackoverflow but I didn't click anything, just reloaded the page. Maybe that's why it was downvoted?

Comment: @boomshanka: No, it was nothing you did. Someone thought this answer was either wrong or more harmful than helpful. I stand behind my answer.

Comment: Yup so do I, just didn't want to start off by making a complete arse of myself - your answer is greatly appreciated :-)